# How to format a date in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, formatting

Im currently doing a program in which stores user information such as their forename, surname and birth date. I'm not very experienced with advanced python functions and I've tried declaring the Birth date as a string value, but this leads to issues where literally any input can be provided, such as "24/05/98" or "24/05/1998".

How can i make the input only work with the format "DD/MM/YYYY"?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's not a great idea to let the user input structured data like this where "literally any input can be provided".

But the [`python-dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package does a good job trying to accommodate.

```
from dateutil import parser

s1 = "24/05/98"
s2 = "24/05/1998"
s3 = "05/24/1998"

dt1 = parser.parse(s1)
dt2 = parser.parse(s2)
dt3 = parser.parse(s3)

print dt1           # 1998-05-24 00:00:00
print dt2           # 1998-05-24 00:00:00
print dt3           # 1998-05-24 00:00:00
print dt1 == dt2    # True
print dt1 == dt3    # True
```

Obviously, this niceness breaks down when it can't figure out the input, for example what order the month and date are in the string:

```
s4 = "1/2/15"       # Feb 1, 2015 in D/M/Y
s5 = "2/1/15"       # Feb 1, 2015 in M/D/Y

dt4 = parser.parse(s4)
dt5 = parser.parse(s5)

print dt4           # 2015-01-02 00:00:00
print dt5           # 2015-02-01 00:00:00
print dt4 == dt5    # False
```

---

**Edit:** Per your comment, if you *know* the format of the data, you can use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

If the input cannot be parsed successfully, given the pattern you provide (in this case, `%d/%m/%Y` or `DD/MM/YYYY`), a `ValueError` will be raised.

```
from datetime import datetime

s1 = "24/05/1998"
s2 = "05/24/1998"
s3 = "24/05/98"

for s in [s1, s2, s3]:
    try:
        dt = datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y")
        print(dt)
    except ValueError:
        print("Failed to parse: %s" % s)
```

Output:

```
1998-05-24 00:00:00           # Parse successful -- dt contains the datetime object
Failed to parse: 05/24/1998   # Parse failed
Failed to parse: 24/05/98     # Parse failed
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, so how would i be able to make it so the only valid format for the input is "DD/MM/YYYY"

Comment: I sort of understand the idea you are expressing to me, Im not very advanced with the software so how would I use this code to test whether, say DOB = input("Provide a DOB"), with the only input being 24/05/98 is valid or not

Comment: @Ynnekb55 try to parse the input with `strptime` (using a try block), if the parsing fails, handle that case in the `except` block.  You might want to review [this section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, i hope it will solve your problem.

```
from time import strptime

date = raw_input("Please enter a date in DD/MM/YYYY format: ")
try:
    parsed = strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
except ValueError as e:
    print "Please retry: {0}".format(e)
#Do your work...
```